# Open Url in app via Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am new in phonegap and web. I create a sample app with cordova 3.4 and i want to change html file for access to a url and show on the screen, or i want create a sample app for send sms and another sample... but i don't know how can write these and i did'nt found any tutorial or sample step by step. How can i open a url and show on the app like google.com (I know about add acess to config.xml ) but i dont know about how can write js and html and java file, i want step by step :) !

And another question is, what is mean of Config.getStartUrl() in super.loadUrl()?

And if you know about a tutorial and resource for start, please say to me.

Thanks for advises

Comment: in your index.html write js code to redirect to another page like `window.location = "http://google.com" `;

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I write "<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location="www.google.com" </script>" but when run the program, i see this error, 'There was a network error.(file:///www.google.com)' Why? What is problem? for access to url, don't need change java file?

Comment: you forgot the "http://"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Config.getStartUrl()** means you declared starting page in your config.xml and get using java. here no need to change java code only need to change config.xml

2) **super.loadUrl()** means you directly call starting page in your web application

3)**config.xml** like AndroidManifest.xml

[tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

[tutorial2](http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/)